# Q : Limiting function value is ∞

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

got this question:

Check if $f_n$ converges uniformly:

$f_n=\sqrt ne^{-nx} , x\in[0,1]$ .

I started checking what the limiting function as n approaches ∞:

$x>0$ , $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{e^{nx}} = 0$(I used L'Hôpital's rule)

$x=0$ , $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{e^{0}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt n}=∞$

I tried checking what it meant when the limiting function value is ∞ at some point but didnt find anything about it.

Does it contradict the possiblity that the function converges uniformly (or converges pointwise in [0,1])?
And if not what does it mean and how should I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\bigl(f_n(0)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge. Therefore, the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not pointwise convergent and therefore it is not uniformly convergent.